# hide video container when there's no video in database to be displayed HTML PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

Below is my html code to display an exercise video from a database:

```
<video id = "video" width="640" height="360" controls = "controls" src="admin/exercise_content/<?php echo $data['exercise_video']?>" alt="Exercise" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag. </video>
```

Sometimes there won't be a exercise video in the database therefore I want to hide this tag. The video sample/container below is displayed if there is no video in the database. Is there any way to hide this video container when there's no video to be displayed?

[image: default video displayed if exercise video empty in database]

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<?php if ( $data['exercise_video'] != '' ) { ?>
<video id = "video" width="640" height="360" controls = "controls"src="admin/exercise_content/<?php echo $data['exercise_video']?>" alt="Exercise" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.       </video>
<?php }  ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
<? if ( trim($data['exercise_video']) != '' ) : ?>
<video id = "video" width="640" height="360" controls = "controls" src="admin/exercise_content/<?php echo $data['exercise_video']?>" alt="Exercise" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag. </video>
<? endif; ?>
```

This prints the video tag only when $data['exercise_video'] is not empty.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Better to use !empty($data['exercise_video']) as your code will throw a notice if it isn't set

Answer (score 1):

Well using

```
<?php if (!empty($data['exercise_video']): ?>
<video id = "video" width="640" height="360" controls = "controls" src="admin/exercise_content/<?php echo $data['exercise_video']?>" alt="Exercise" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag. </video>
<?php endif ;?>
```

Would be much better.. Try it.. :)